# rHow do I force a web page is immediately rendered during javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, rendering

## How to force different behaviour of the Interpreter/compiler

Note that I am a beginner to Javascript and HTML.  I am familiar with traditional compiled languages with some MVC exposure so its probably a basic lack of understanding of how this model of WebAPI + Javascript engine hangs together.

I have a piece of javascript that is intended to slowly increase the text shown in an

element.   I'm trying to simulate an old-fashioned dumb terminal at a super slow baud rate.

The problem I have is that the page in the browser doesn't appear to visually update until the script is completed.  Clearly, 'by design'.   See my code below where Im trying simple manipulation of a text string of a

element.

There is definitely some science behind how the `webAPI` orders execution stuff through the interpreter.   What I need to do is be able to override the behaviour of the Interpreter to force it to go render the page after each call to add some text to a

element.   Or, find a different way to do it?  I'm not sure what that would be?  perhaps a GIF or some animation feature in webAPI.  Closest I could find was here ->. https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-have-the-marquee-effect-without-using-the-marquee-tag-with-css-javascript-and-jquery.html
but that seems to require a maths degree whereas I just wanted to manage some simple text string

My code which was intended to simply manipulate the text content of a

element, but... sadly doesnt work beacuse the loop to add the text char by char is completed first before the collation of HTML calls are all rendered at once.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="textParagraph"></p>
  </body>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript

```js
'use strict';

document.getElementById('textParagraph').textContent = '  ';

let txt = 'some text';
let newStr = '';
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

/*
I am calling a function that recurses because I thought the FOR loop may affect the behavior of how javascript was executing the rendering?!  I was wrong!  it appears 
*/

recurse();

function recurse() {
  console.log(x);
  newStr = txt.substr(0, x);
  console.log(newStr);

  addCharToString();

  for (y = 0; y <= 100000000; y++) {
    let j = (y * y) / 2;
  } //I added some delay here in the hope that it may trigger the browser to quickly render the screen ;o)
  x++;

  if (x <= txt.length) recurse();
}

function addCharToString() {
  document.getElementById('textParagraph').textContent = newStr;
  console.log(x + ' whilst in addchartostring');
}

alert('mid script');

y = 0; //

secondRecurseTest();

console.log('about to start the next loop...');

for (y = 0; y <= 900000000; y++) {
  let j = (y * y) / 2;
}

function secondRecurseTest() {
  console.log('inside secondrecurse test');

  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('inside delayed functioncall');
  }, 1000);

  y++;

  if (y <= 10) secondRecurseTest();
}

alert('end of script');
```

Comment: What is expected behavior...slow typing effect?

Comment: hey Charlietfl, yes..  like an old telex machine or low baudrate dumb terminal (green screen)

Comment: Shouldn't be a hard web search to find such solutions

Comment: @charlietfl,  well, it is hard as I haven't been able to find the answer, hence asking the question here.

Comment: Really? https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+typing+animation

Comment: ok, you got me there Charlietfl.  In my defence, I was trying to solve the problem in exactly the same way as your link points to, however, instead of using 'innerHTML', as proposed in the link, I was using 'textContent', and textContent is treated by the interpreter in a completely different way.

Comment: @charlietfl, I can't award points to comments. if you care, add an answer to my question and can aware a point.

Answer (score 0):

I could be terrible wrong, but paste the script into your body and try it again

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="textParagraph"></p>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>


</html>
```

**Try this too:**

```
<html>   
  <head>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" /> 
  </head> 

  <body>     
    <p id="textParagraph"></p>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>    
  </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: Good spot Gismo.  I hadn't noticed, or even thought about the location of script.  I moved it, but that didn't appear to make any difference at all.

Comment: Also, I noticed that other page changes made at the beginning of the script, and indeed in the HTML where the <p> text is reset,  is not applied either!   I assume the WebAPI/Browser (whatever is doing the interpreting) is making decisions on ordering the rendering intelligently?    or I'm missing something key!

Comment: @Brianos Add `window.addEventListener("load", _youfunction_ );` to your code. The **load events** allows to load the JS after 100% website loading.

Comment: Thanks Gismo, yes I tried that.  I also tried Document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",.....

Comment: soooooo..... I'm guessing there's another way to force the Interpreter to behave differently.   obviously,... this is way over the top just to drop some characters onto a textfield one after the other!!   there must be other ways to fix it.... but, I kept researching this because it does present a fundamental question around how the interpreter for JS works & integrateds with the webapi?

Comment: Can you try this code pls:

`<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="script.js" asynch></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="textParagraph"></p>
  </body>

  
</html>` The **asynch** forces the browser to load it simultaneously to the website.

Comment: Can you try this code too pls: `<html>   <head>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />     <script src="script.js" defer></script>   </head>    <body>     <p id="textParagraph"></p>   </body>     </html>` 

The **defer** forces the browser to load it only when the website is finished.

Comment: thanks Gismo, yes, I tried both defer and async earlier this week and neither made any difference.  The challenge is the difference between how some webApi calls work.  using element.innerHTML forces a parsing of HTML content and rendering, whereas element.textcontent='' does not force a re-rendering.

Comment: Okay, did you consol.log the document.readystate? with good log placing, you should see the states.